# android what is the minimum software that must be present in my PC to detect my android phone

Tags: usb-drivers

Hi this is very basic question

I have an android phone and when i connect it to few of the PCs in office i can see that "device drivers getting installed" and device ready to use

but few machines its giving "device driver not installed"

I have not specifically installed any software in these PCs to detect the phone.

So please explain me how it is getting rightly installed in few and not in others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you forget install the android usb driver, look this:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

and

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

when you finish this work, if it also dont work, please try get your device specialized driver.

Comment: Thank you very much . What i am using is a prototype phone ( prototype for something to be released ) and it doesnt have any driver fro OEM . So what i think is that the devices which it was detected already has android SDK installed. SO might be the phone is getting detected with the google USB drivers.